# Error in AG Dashboard when looking at a Distributed AG

Tags: sql-server, ssms, distributed-availability-groups

I have a Distributed AG, but whenever I go to look at the AG Dashboard it says "An error occurred on the Always On Dashboard".  When I click for details I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Is this a known bug?  Or is there possibly something about the setup of my DAG that's causing this?  I get this error in both

- SSMS 2016 16.5.3 (build 13.0.16106.4)
- SSMS 2017 17.4 (build 14.0.17213.0)

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using, and which specific versions of SSMS? Seems like an SSMS bug if I had to guess.

Comment: @LowlyDBA i may have added that into my question between you reading and writing your comment

Comment: I don't see your SQL Server version anywhere, and I was looking for the full version of SSMS, i.e. 17.4 vs 17.6 as it is being updated frequently now and has had its fair share of bugs along the way.

Comment: @LowlyDBA Yes..recently SSMS updates are actually causing more issues than fixing it. I too second you on the version issue. Use latest SSMS version and check.

Comment: @LowlyDBA updated

Answer (score 2):

As a couple users mentioned in the comments, if you are not actually having *problems* with the AG, this is likely a bug with SSMS.

You mentioned you're on 17.4, and I see in [the release notes for 17.6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-changelog-ssms?view=sql-server-2017#ssms-176download-sql-server-management-studio-ssmsmd) that there are several fixes for AG issues, including:

> Fixed an issue when the primary is down and manually failover to secondary, a NullReferenceException will be thrown.

(a `NullReferenceException` in .NET classically includes the message you mentioned - "*Object reference not set to an instance of an object*")

You should try updating to 17.6 (build 14.0.17230.0) to see if the problem is resolved there.